# Get the first 2 items from a column to make another Column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a table with a DateTime Column as shown below. The time Interval is in hours

```
ID  TimeInterval   Temperature
1   00:00:00            27
2   01:00:00            26
3   02:00:00            24
4   03:00:00            24
5   04:00:00            25
```

I tried to use the time interval for plotting. However, I got an error
`float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'`

So,  I want to extract the first two numbers of Column TimeInterval and have it into a new column.
Any ideas how to extract that?

Comment: Is the column a "string" or a datetime object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strftime` with `%H` for hours

```
# Create test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'TimeInterval': ['00:00:00', '01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00'], 'Temperature': [27, 26, 24, 24, 25]})

# Change the format to %H:%M:%S.
df['TimeInterval'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeInterval'], format='%H:%M:%S')

# Create a new column
df['new'] = df['TimeInterval'].dt.strftime('%H')
```

output:

```
ID  TimeInterval            Temperature new
1   1900-01-01 00:00:00     27          00
2   1900-01-01 01:00:00     26          01
3   1900-01-01 02:00:00     24          02
4   1900-01-01 03:00:00     24          03
5   1900-01-01 04:00:00     25          04
```

Comment: I get an error as follows. ```Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values```.

Comment: Did you use pd.to_datetime(df['TimeInterval'], format='%H:%M:%S') at the first?

Comment: this is what I have used in my solution. I have commented the other one on my notebook too. I appreciate both.

Answer (score 1):

If the "TimeInterval" column is a string ...
you can select the first 2 characters from it and parse it later on into an integer:

```
df["new"] = df["TimeInterval"].str[:2].astype(int)
```

But that would be an ugly solution.

Here is a better solution

```
# test data
df = pd.DataFrame([{'TimeInterval':'00:00:00'}, 
                   {'TimeInterval':'01:00:00'}])

# cast it to a datetime object
df['TimeInterval'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeInterval'], format='%H:%M:%S')

# select the hours
df['hours'] = df['TimeInterval'].dt.hour
```